# Do affixes and clitics belong to an own part of speech, part of sentence or another category ?

Tags: grammar, theoretical-linguistics, parts-of-speech, affixes, clitics

Birds, flowers, children belong to the part of speech of nouns,
to fish, to pick, to play to verbs,
swift, smelly, nice to adjectives

those are the easy ones, what about clitics and affixes and such alike, do they belong to a category within the same linguistic realm or sth. different?

What is the connection between part of speeches and affixes/clitics that makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

There is no necessary correlation between clitics or affixes and parts of speech.

In English *'ll* is a verb (contraction of *will*); *n't* is a negator (contraction of *not*, traditionally treated in the catch-all POS of 'adverb', but it doesn't behave like any other adverb); *-me* and *-'em* are pronouns (as in *gimme* and *got'em*)

In French *me* and *y* are pronoun clitics, *ne* is (part of) a negator.